# Data entered not stored correctly

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I have a problem with the Compiler for the programming language COBOL.
I use the program "OpenCobolIDE" (GnuCOBOL 1.1 Mingw).

Firstly here is the code of an example program.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. HelloWorld.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  name           pic x(32).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   beginn section.
        DISPLAY "What is your Name?: " with no advancing.
        accept name.
        DISPLAY "Your Name: ",name .
        STOP RUN.
   END PROGRAM HelloWorld.
```

After typing my name, "Albert", the console doesn't send the message "Your Name: Albert" back. The Console is after "Albert" empty. 
But if I set the length of the string name to 6, because my name is 6 characters long, then the program works correctly and the console shows "Your Name: Albert".

In addition to this ,the clause `with no advancing` doesn't work correctly.
When I use this command the console doesn't print "What is your Name?", it skips the line and I have to enter my name first and after entering my name the console shows: "What is your Name?: Albert". But in the .exe of the compiled program the command line `with no advancing` works correctly.

Why is it so, and how I can repair that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you use the embedded python console OCIDE uses for better integration. The side effect is: it is not fully functional, as soon as you start to use anything other than very simple `ACCEPT`/`DISPLAY` you should disable it:

Preferences (F2) -> Tab Run -> check "Run in external terminal"

BTW: The windows installation of OpenCOBOL IDE ships with the latest official MinGW package of GnuCOBOL. This currently is 1.1 but *very* soon will be GnuCOBOL 2.0 rc2 (or final), I highly suggest to use this one instead of the older GnuCOBOL 1.1. You can get an unofficial [preview version with the rc1](https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/contrib/thread/99acea66/) and/or stay tuned for the new version (which will likely be added to OCIDE, too).

**Edit**: As found in the comment:

> The Problem was the old version of GnuCOBOL 1.1, because after updating it works correctly!

Comment: The Problem was the old version of GnuCOBOL 1.1, because after updating its works correcty!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'll add this to my answer.